# How to delete duplicate rows when duplicate entries exist in a single column

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to create an Excel VBA code that will delete an entire row when duplicates are found in a single column. I have created code, but for some reason Excel crashes every time I run it. Can anyone help me?

```
Sub Test()
    For i = 1 To 25
        a = Cells(i, 1).Value
        b = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
        If a = b Then
            Rows(i + 1).Delete
            i = i - 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of two things can make this code problematic:

1- If you have error values in column A (i.e. `#NA`) the comparison `If a = b` will fail and the code will stop with an error code `type mismatch`

2- The code can enter an infinite loop (that's why you think that Excel *"crashes"*) because when you reach the end of the range you get only empty rows, so that the comparison `a = b` always succeeds (`empty = empty`) and hence you keep deleting rows and looping.....

Therefore the correct approach is to apply what is usual: loop from the bottom to the top when you're deleting.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim i as Long
    For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 2 step -1
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then Rows(i).Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

Finally, beware that this code does not remove any duplicates but only duplicates that comes beneath each other. This seems to be your goal from seeing your initial code.

Answer (score 0):

By using the code below you can delete duplicate values:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
```